# What kind of parameters should I set to a message deploy function in WINAPI

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I am learning WINAPI. When I want to programming to get message and then to do some specific operation. I got an error from VC6.0.

For example, I want get wm_keydown message.

code like this:

```
// .h file
int MainDlg_OnKeyDown(HWND hwnd,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

|

```
HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, MainDlg_OnKeyDown);

int MainDlg_OnKeyDown(HWND hwnd, int id,  WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return 1;
}
```

error:

```
error C2660: 'MainDlg_OnKeyDown' : function does not take 5 parameters
```

there are seems only 4 parameters from HANDLE_MSG Macro. I know that when I use WM_COMMAND I can create a function with 4 parameters.

```
void MainDlg_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify);
```

But what about WM_NOTIFY, WM_KEYDOWN or other messages?
How should I know that how many parameters and what kind of parameters should I set when I create message deploy function to a message. I did not find my answer on MSDN and google.Does any one know this? What does MFC do?

Comment: Do you look at windowsx.h header?

Comment: Thanks. I find this.`/* void Cls_OnKey(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, BOOL fDown, int cRepeat, UINT flags) */
#define HANDLE_WM_KEYDOWN(hwnd, wParam, lParam, fn) \
    ((fn)((hwnd), (UINT)(wParam), TRUE, (int)(short)LOWORD(lParam), (UINT)HIWORD(lParam)), 0L)
#define FORWARD_WM_KEYDOWN(hwnd, vk, cRepeat, flags, fn) \
    (void)(fn)((hwnd), WM_KEYDOWN, (WPARAM)(UINT)(vk), MAKELPARAM((cRepeat), (flags)))`. But I did not find something about WM_NOTIFY. @Xearinox

Comment: If I remember correctly, HANDLE_WM_NOTIFY is in the commctrl.h.

Comment: Thanks. You can edit your comment as an answer. It is helpful for newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HANDLE_MSG macro is defined in Windowsx.h header.

Note: To use message cracker for WM_NOTIFY you must use HANDLE_WM_NOTIFY macro defined in commctrl.h header.